# How to get variable's value in this loop in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying to filter for multiple words using a loop but following is not working:

```
function! Myfilter (...)
   for s in a:000
     v/s/d 
   endfor
endfunction
```

It deletes all lines that do not contain the letter `s` rather than the value of `s`. How can I get value of `s` in statement `v/s/d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`:execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute) command is designed precisely for this task of 
evaluating an expression and executing it as an *Ex* command:

```
exec 'v/' . s . '/d'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Deletes all lines other than those that contain all of the function's arguments**

```
function! Myfilter0 (...)
  exec 'v/\(.*' . join(a:000, '\)\@=\(.*') . '\)\@=/d'
endfunction
```

**Example buffer**

```
word1 beta word2
a word1 b word2 c
a word2 b word1 c word3 d
a word2 b word3 c word1 d
word1 delta
epsilon
```

**Example function call**

```
:call Myfilter("word1", "word2", "word3")
```

**Example result**

```
a word2 b word1 c word3 d
a word2 b word3 c word1 d
```

**Note**

Uses regex lookahead to match words in any order. This is what the example regex looks like after substitution and without the escape characters for clarity:

```
:v/(.*word1)@=(.*word2)@=(.*word3)@=/d
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more efficient solution would be to compose a regex from your parameters, and to use it to remove non matching lines.

```
exe 'v/\('.join(a:000, '\|').'\)/d_'
```

Comment: This keeps only lines that contain *any* of the arguments. I think he wants to keep only lines that contain *all* of the arguments.

Comment: @JimU. You're right. Along the way I got my logic inverted.